# String to int/float

Tags: php

I have a number that comes as a string from an input. It could be `"450.021"` or `"30"`. I need to determine whether it is `int` or a `float` number. How do I do that?

I tried with `intval` but apparently floating numbers are floored and in my case it is not going to help me.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php read this php manual

Comment: Have you tried searching the string for a `.`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: @PraveenM No but I need to also allow it to be a string in case it is a text.

Comment: You can try regex to determine if the string has numbers and if there's a `.` between numbers. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php .  https://regexr.com/

Comment: `([0-9])\.([0-9])` theres most simple regex

Comment: @PraveenM That actually will work. Great idea! Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to know the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Very naiv approach

```
    foreach(["342.23", "30"] as $a) {
        if( (float)(int)$a === (float)$a ) {
            echo "int";
        } else {
            echo "float";
        }
    }
```

But this won't catch cases where you parse "340.0".

Edit: Digging a bit more:

```
    foreach(["342.23", "30"] as $a) {
        $is_float = filter_var($a, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
        $is_int = filter_var($a, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

        if( $is_float && $is_int ) {
            echo $a . " is Int";
        } else if( $is_float && !$is_int ) {
            echo $a . " is Float";
        }

    }
```